# how to check if iap transactions are finished?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

i am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase this package for in-app-purchases. i sold credit but users can receive more credit then they paid, as shown in this video :

https://youtu.be/Bo5MQdi5wGY

how can i fix this bug ? help me , please. thanks.

All relevant lines of code are in below;

code:

```
Future<void> initPlatformState() async {

await Purchases.setDebugLogsEnabled(true);
await Purchases.setup("RowkOdfhhydoMREZKRckltCNUNzJqgnj");
String platformVersion;
try {
  platformVersion = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.platformVersion;
} on PlatformException {
  platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
}
var result = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initConnection;
print('result: $result');
if (!mounted) return;

setState(() {
  _platformVersion = platformVersion;
});

try {
  String msg = await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.consumeAllItems;
  print('consumeAllItems: $msg');

} catch (err) {
  print('consumeAllItems error: $err');
}
_conectionSubscription =
    FlutterInappPurchase.connectionUpdated.listen((connected) {
      print('connected: $connected');

    });




_purchaseUpdatedSubscription =
    FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseUpdated.listen((productItem) {
      // String deviceId = await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId;

      dispose();
      initPlatformState();

      //FlutterInappPurchase.instance.finishTransaction(productItem);



      if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit10") {

        print("CREDİT 10 !!!");

        addCredit(deviceid, "10").then((value) => {

          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Successfully loaded 10 credit !...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });

      } else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit20") {
        print("CREDİT 20 !!!");

        addCredit(deviceid, "20").then((value) => {



          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "20 credits successfully loaded !...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });


      } else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit50") {
        print("CREDİT 50 !!!");

        addCredit(deviceid, "50").then((value) => {

          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "50 credits successfully loaded !...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });


      } else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit100") {
        print("CREDİT 100 !!!");

        addCredit(deviceid, "100").then((value) => {

          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "100 crdits successfully loaded!...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )

        });


      }  else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcreditvip"){


        isPremium = true;
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "VIP successfully loaded!...",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0
        );


      }
    });

_purchaseErrorSubscription =
    FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseError.listen((purchaseError) {
      print('purchase-error: $purchaseError');
    });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is a bug in this plugin and it is still open on [Github](https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_inapp_purchase/issues/260)

The reason why you are getting more credits is because the `purchaseUpdated` listener receives multiple callbacks on iOS and hence your `addCredit()` function is called multiple times.

As a workaround, you can use the transactionId as a flag and avoid calling the code inside the `purchaseUpdated` listener multiple times.

Add a check

```
if(lastTransactionId!=productItem.transactionId)
```

And initialize the lastTransactionId outside the `if` statement body

```
 lastTransactionId = productItem.transactionId;
```

**Complete code:**

Declare a global variable

```
String lastTransactionId;
```

And then update your listener code with this

```
_purchaseUpdatedSubscription =
    FlutterInappPurchase.purchaseUpdated.listen((productItem) {
      // String deviceId = await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId;
      if(lastTransactionId!=productItem.transactionId){  //Added this to avoid multiple callbacks for the same transaction
        
      dispose();
      initPlatformState();

      //FlutterInappPurchase.instance.finishTransaction(productItem);



      if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit10") {
        print("CREDİT 10 !!!");
        addCredit(deviceid, "10").then((value) => {
          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Successfully loaded 10 credit !...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });

      } else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit20") {
        print("CREDİT 20 !!!");
        addCredit(deviceid, "20").then((value) => {
          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "20 credits successfully loaded !...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });
      } else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit50") {
        print("CREDİT 50 !!!");
        addCredit(deviceid, "50").then((value) => {
          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "50 credits successfully loaded !...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });

      } else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcredit100") {
        print("CREDİT 100 !!!");
        addCredit(deviceid, "100").then((value) => {
          tipController.updateCredit(),
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "100 crdits successfully loaded!...",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16.0
        )
        });
      }  else if (productItem.productId == "oddinbetcreditvip"){
        isPremium = true;
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "VIP successfully loaded!...",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.SNACKBAR,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0
        );
      }
      }
      lastTransactionId = productItem.transactionId; //finally initialize your lastTransactionId with productItem.transactionId, outside the if statement
    });
```

PS: You should call the `await FlutterInappPurchase.instance.initConnection;` method only once.

I hope this answer helps!